# Дневник Великой княжны Ольги Николаевны

Tags: литература

Знаю, что Великая княжна Ольга Николаевна очень любила произведение Эдмона Ростана "Орлёнок". За 6 часов до расстрела она переписывала эту пьесу в свой дневник. В Интернете только отрывки из него. Подскажите, пожалуйста, если вы знаете, где можно найти его.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь можно скачать книгу "Сирано де Бержерак", в ней и эта пьеса:

http://lib.rus.ec/a/10519/sa-a

Или забить в поисковик "Э.Ростан "Орлёнок" - читать онлайн".

Comment: Я "Орлёнка" читала. Меня интересуют дневники княжны.

Comment: Видимо, это всё, что от них осталось. Часть дневников была сожжена ранее, во время обысков в Тобольске и Екатеринбурге, часть в ГОХРАНе пропала.Когда всё рассекретили, там уже мало чего было.